# Force nginx 1.0 on Amazon EC AMI

Tags: nginx, redhat, repository, amazon-ami

I'm trying to install nginx from the nginx official repositories.

I downloaded the nginx-release-rhel*.rpm from nginx.org and installed it with yum. But, altough a new nginx-debug package is available from the new nginx repo, the available version for nginx is 0.8.54.

What can I do to force the installation of nginx 1.0.X?

Edit: More information with configuration files.

This is the `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo` file:

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

This is what `uname -a` has to say:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-XX-XXX-XX-YYY 2.6.35.14-107.1.36.amzn1.i686 #1 SMP Thu Feb 16 23:14:37 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Finally, this is the output of `yum info nginx`:

```
$ yum info nginx
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
amzn-main                                                                                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                  | 2.3 kB     00:00     
nginx                                                                                                                         | 1.3 kB     00:00     
10 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Available Packages
Name        : nginx
Arch        : i686
Version     : 0.8.54
Release     : 1.4.amzn1
Size        : 385 k
Repo        : amzn-updates
Summary     : Robust, small and high performance HTTP and reverse proxy server
URL         : http://nginx.net/
License     : BSD
Description : Nginx [engine x] is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3
            : proxy server written by Igor Sysoev.
```

Comment: Did you enable the yum repo as described on the nginx download page http://wiki.nginx.org/Install ? If so, can you show your /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo file?

Comment: @cjc I just added more information. Hope it helps to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's hitting the Amazon repo and ignoring the nginx one.  Try doing this:

`yum --showduplicates list nginx`

See if you can see the 1.x packages from that.

Then, with the specific name, do something like:

`yum install nginx-1.0.13-1`

to install that specific package.  You may need to remove the currently installed 0.8 version beforehand.

Comment: It only shows nginx 0.8.54 from amzn-main and amzn-updates. On every yum command, it always tells me that "10 packages excluded due to repository priority protections". Would  nginx be blacklisted? how do I take it out from that list?

Comment: Take a look at your /etc/yum.repos.d directory and look for lines like "priority=" in the various configurations.  You can add in a "priority=1" line for the nginx repo.  Take a look at http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities

Comment: Yeah! that solved the problem. They main thing to do is, as you stated, to add "priority=1" to the nginx repo.